# Equation with Taylor, Change of Variable and Hopital two times, without using notable limit?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Verify, using Taylor, a change of variable, the theorem of Hopital two times and WITHOUT any notable special limit, the following equation:

if $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$  such that
$$f(0)=1, \quad f'(0) =0, \quad f''(0) =-1$$
then for every $a\in \mathbb{R}$ 
$$\lim _{x\to +\infty} \left( f(\frac{a}{\sqrt{x}}) \right)^x = e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note: this does not use L'Hospital, but does use change of variables and Taylor (only noticed requirement to use L'Hospital  after completing the answer...). Hope it still helps.

For any $t$ in some neighborhood of zero, $f(t)>0$ because $f(0)=1$ and $f$ is continuous. Therefore,

$$ f(t)^x = e^{x \ln f(t)}.$$

Now by Taylor expansion, for any $t$,

$$f(t) = 1  + f''(c)\frac{t^2}{2},$$

where $c$ is between $0$ and $t$.

Therefore for $t= \frac{a}{\sqrt{x}}$, we have

$$ x \ln f(t) = x \ln (1+f''(c) \frac{a^2}{2x})=(*)$$

By Taylor expansion, for $|z|<1$.

$$\ln (1+z)= z - \frac{z^2}{2(1+{\bar{c}})^2},$$

where $\bar{c}$ is between $0$ and $z$.

For $x$ large enough, letting $z= f''(c) \frac{a^2}{2x}$, we clearly have $|z|<1$, and so

$$ (*) = x \frac{ f''(c) a^2}{2x} + x  \frac{1}{2(1+\bar{c})^2}\frac{f''(c)^2 a^4}{ 4x^2}=\frac{ f''(c) a^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2(1+\bar{c})^2}\frac{f''(c)^2 a^4}{ 8x}.$$

Finally, as $x\to \infty$, $t\to 0$, hence $c\to 0$ and also $z\to 0$, so  ${\bar{c}}\to 0$. Since $f''$ is continuous and $f''(0)=-1$, we obtain

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} (*) = -\frac{a^2}{2}.$$

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(\frac{a}{\sqrt{x}})^x = \lim_{x\to \infty} e^{ (*) } =e^{\lim_{x\to \infty} (*)} = e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}.$$

The result follows from continuity of the exponential function.